# How to define a widget to be hidden in the design phase?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Good afternoon,

I'm in a real messy situation here: I have a window, which contains a widget I would like to turn invisible. You might think "*How easy, just add the `<widget>.VISIBLE=FALSE` line at the moment the widget is shown*", but there's the catch: my application is an ununderstanble spaghetti of scope-defines, global variables (more than 200 of them), doing lots of things in background, ..., so I would simply like to do the following:

```
annoying_widget AT ROW 11.38 COL 52.86
      VIEW-AS TOGGLE-BOX HIDDEN
      SIZE 13 BY .77
```

But, obviously, this does not work, as `HIDDEN` is not a part of a `VIEW-AS` command. How can I achieve this at design-time?

Comment: Your question seems to match your code - also an ununderstandable mess of spaghetti. Invisible is the opposite of visible - so why you would want to add visible = true when you want it to be invisible beats me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the AppBuilder.

Have you tried unchecking the VISIBLE and checking the HIDDEN attributes in the properties of the widget?